# Load first blur image

Tags: android, tags, imageview

How to load image from URL like Instagram before 100% load original image? How I can get blur image and load into imageview?

**I try one dep. Glide**

```
GlideApp.with((Activity) context)
    .load(video.video_thumnail)
    .centerCrop()
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .skipMemoryCache(true)  //No memory cache
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)   //No disk cache
    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            mainViewHolder.imgVideoImage.setImageDrawable(resource);
            return true;
        }
    })
    .into(mainViewHolder.imgVideoImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html) it as an awesome image loading library made by Facebook and it comes with the functionality to load a placeholder image of low quality while the actual full resolution image downloads.

But the problem is you need to have a small thumbnail somewhere from where you can load the placeholder image, Apps like **Instagram** have large database where they have images on different compression.

Once you have that you can use the `DraweeController` object to load the images in your `DraweeView` like this

```
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setLowResImageRequest(ImageRequest.fromUri(YOUR_LOW_RES_URL))
                    .setImageRequest(ImageRequest.fromUri(YOUR_HIGH_RES_URL))
                    .setOldController(draweeView.getController())
                    .build();
            draweeView.getHierarchy().setProgressBarImage(new FrescoCircularImageLoader());
            //Assigning the controller to DraweeView 
            draweeView.setController(controller);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like all images that you get from url first comes blur and then load into imageView then your have to use Android NDK and OpenCV